# Was könnte »Oumadoumouwoudou« auf Standarddeutsch sein?

Tags: meaning, dialect, bavarian

In der Süddeutschen Zeitung vom 7. Mai berichtet Sebastian Beck in der Kolumne *Unter Bayern*, betitelt [*Neues aus der Wirtshausforschung*](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/bayern/unter-bayern-neues-aus-der-wirtshausforschung-1.2982194) über Stammtischbesuche von Journalisten. Er erzählt vom Besuch eines Stammtischs in der nördlichen Oberpfalz nahe Kemnath (Landkreis Tirschenreuth).

> Am Tisch sitzen sechs oder sieben Leute. Ihre Unterhaltung wirkt rege, aber nicht hitzig. Ein Mann fragt sinngemäß: „Oumadoumouwoudou?“ Der Gast antwortet: „Von der *Süddeutschen Zeitung*, München.“ Ein Stimmungskiller. Schweigen am Tisch.

Des Bairischen bin ich eigentlich mächtig, aber zugegebenermaßen verstehe ich Leute immer schwieriger, je weiter weg vom Lech sie herstammen – die (nördliche) Oberpfalz ist ja der diametrale Gegensatz. Das Wort (oder der Satz) *Oumadoumouwoudou* sagt mir nichts, und mir gelingt es nicht, ihn auf verständliches Bairisch zurückzuführen. (Ich nehme an, dass hier Klischees über die Oberpfalz bedient werden, eine besonders *ou*-reiche Variante speziell herausgesucht wurde, und künstlich unverständlicher gemacht wurden, aber selbst damit komme ich nicht weiter.)

Wie könnte die ursprüngliche Frage, die der Kolumnist als *Oumadoumouwoudou* widergegeben hat, gelautet haben?

Comment: Irgendwas muss hier bei der Transkription shief gegangen sein. Ich komme einfach nicht auf irgendeinen Zusammenhang oder passende Uebersetzung. Grinsen musste ich trotzdem. ;)

Comment: "Und von wo kommst Du?", muss es wohl irgendwie heißen. Oder von wem. Oder "Und wo kommst Du her". Plus beliebige Füllwörter, wa, gelle, nicht?

Comment: Anfrage bei Autor und Zeitung läuft.

Comment: Ich denke, dass das hier nicht auf einen sinvollen Satz zurückgeführt werden kann, weil das nicht gewünscht ist. Mir scheint es eher darum zu gehen, die Unverständlichkeit des lokalen Dialekts hervorzuheben. Genauso hätte der Autor auch "selrghseltiugh" schreiben können, aber dem hätte der lautliche Lokalkolorit gefehlt.

Comment: Das hat wohl jeder DIalekt - Die "Abschreckungswaffe". Schwaben sagen dann ein "Kaschmermalmeiradradra?"

Comment: @tofro Das schöne ist ja, dass ich dein schwäbisches Beispiel zu 80+ % verstehe … ;)

Comment: Irgendwas Neues zu diesem? Hab hier ein Sternchen markiert, das interessiert mich jetzt dann doch.

Comment: @Marakai. Leider keine Antwort via Twitter bisher.

Comment: In diesem Zusammenhang eine kurze Minute der Wertschätzung für die stetig steigende Zahl der gut besetzten Kundendienstteams in Social-Media. z.B. von DHL, oder den DVB. Die SZ gehört leider noch nicht dazu :D

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu Vielleicht will die SZ nach dem 2. tweet deine Kreditkarte oder sonstwie ein Abo. >.<

Comment: Also "umadum" kenn ich als rundherum, rundum siehe Duden http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/umadum aber den -sagen wir- gesamten Ausdruck nicht! Interessant wäre die Frage wie gut der Autor selbst mit dem Dialekt klar kommt.

Comment: Ist zwar etwas besserwisserisch aber genau genommen ist der *tag* *bavarian* falsch, denn das Wort ist ja (tiefstes) ober-pfälzisch, wie es im Text steht und mir ein Oberbayer, den ich nach der möglichen Bedeutung gefragt habe klargemacht hat.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Nein, das ist falsch. Oberpfälzisch gehört – im Gegensatz zu Ober*fränkisch* oder Schwäbisch und wie die verschiedenen in Österreich gesprochenen Dialekte – zu den bairischen Dialekten.

Comment: @Jan dann habe ich was dazu gelernt :)

Comment: Ich bin des Bayrischen gar nicht mächtig. Erstens halte ich das Wort "SINNGEMÄSS" im Text für entscheidend. Zweitens, müsste ich raten, würde ich auf etwas mit "...machst Du... " tippen.

Comment: Ich komme aus der Oberpfalz und das ist weit von irgendetwas entfernt, das ich verstehen könnte.

Answer (score 4):

Ich schreibe meinen Kommentar nochmal als Antwort, denn je öfter ich über diese Frage stolpere, desto mehr bin ich davon überzeugt, dass ich richtig liege :-)

Ich denke, dass das hier überhaupt nicht auf einen sinvollen Satz zurückgeführt werden kann, weil das auch gar nicht gewünscht (bzw. die Intention des Autors) ist.

Mir scheint es eher darum zu gehen, die Unverständlichkeit des lokalen Dialekts hervorzuheben. Genauso hätte der Autor auch "selrghseltiugh" schreiben können, aber dem hätte der lautliche Lokalkolorit gefehlt, für den die Oberpfälzer ja bekannt sind :-)

Klar könnte man jetzt orakeln, dass hier ja ein *dou* (da), *mou* (muss) und *wou* (wo) vorkommen, aber ich vermute, der Autor hat schlicht versucht, aufzuschreiben, was ein Außenstehender hört/versteht, wenn er in einem Gasthof am Stammtisch Einheimische "belauscht".

Comment: Macht Sinn. Wir haben damals auch mit "houdabouwou" Spott über gewisse niederbayerische Dialekte betrieben. Heisst gar nichts, sondern gibt nur den Tonfall wieder. Wir waren nämlich zivilisierte Oberbayern! :D

Comment: @Marakai »Es is verbouden mit am Knouden am douden Kojouden am Bouden die Houden zu verknouden«? ;)

Comment: @Jan We wir im Englischen sagen: Don't make me come over there! :D

Comment: Downvote - warum?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: weil deine Theorie genauso wacklig ist wie die meiner gelöschten Antwort. Aufklären kann das nur einer, der in diesem Dialekt zu Hause ist.

Comment: @äüö Nein, das ist sie nicht. Zum Einen komme ich aus dem Mittelfränkischen, und das ist jetzt dialektmäßig nicht unbedingt *sooo* weit weg von der Oberpfalz. Zum Anderen ist bei Deiner Antwort klar, dass Du in keinem der beiden Dialekte zuhause bist, denn sonst wüsstest Du, dass *auch* nicht *ou*, *mal* nicht *ma* und *du* nicht *dou* gesprochen werden. Und zum Dritten ergeben Deine Sätze nicht mal im Ansatz Sinn - viele Menschen, die Dialekt sprechen, können konsistente Sätze formulieren ;-) Auch Oberpfälzer. Meistens.

Comment: In diversen Kneipen habe ich schon Leute so reden hören... ;)

Comment: Schrecklich, was der Alkohol mit Menschen macht :)